# Java Async Programming with JFrame Table

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I am coding a artifical intelligence example in Java. But I want to do some calculations about learning method and write in JTable in my form. But I am disappointed with `Thread.sleep(1000)` command. Because this pauses all frame and not doing changes in real time in JTable. I want to write some code after writing table and show users changes for a second and less. How can I use <kbd>Multithreading</kbd> in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're calling `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the UI thread, which causes the UI itself to pause for 1s. You should never call that method on the UI thread. Instead you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (see [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))) to avoid hogging the UI thread while you're doing work.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that event processing and painting is done within the same thread.  Any operation (like `Thread.sleep`) which blocks this thread, will prevent it from processing new events or repainting the screen.

Swing is also not thread safe, so updates to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

Instead, you could use:

- A Swing `Timer`, set to repeat every 1 second, which, when triggered, will execute it's event notification within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- A `SwingWorker`, which would allow you to use `Thread.sleep` within it's `doInBackground` method, but provides `publish`/`process` methods which can be used to sync updates back to the Event Dispatching Thread safety
- A `Thread` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, which makes the entire process of ensuring that updates are synchronized with the EDT correctly up to you.

See:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

for more details

For example:

- [Values repeating when Populating a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496126/values-repeating-when-populating-a-jtable/16496193#16496193)
- [How to refresh data in JTable I am using TableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785982/how-to-refresh-data-in-jtable-i-am-using-tablemodel/16786120#16786120)

Answer (score 0):

Have the class that implements the DefaultTableModel query an object for new updates on a scheduler.  If the object that listens for all updates is shared, you'll be able to see everyone's changes.

One good way to do this would be a web service.  Even better?  A push model from central listener to all remote DefaultTableModel listeners whenever a new event arrives.

You shouldn't be using `Thread` anymore.  Since JDK 6, the preferred way to do this would be `ExecutorService`.