# Display data in jtable each x seconds

Tags: java, jtable, resultset

I have the code bellow to read data in database and then show this in the jtable with multiple color lines. This works fine but only in the last iteration. In this example I have put a for command with 5 iterations and the frame is visible from begining of execution but the rows in jtable only appears at the end of 5 iterations. I want to show the data obtained in each iteration with the info gather from each select to database  actualized (bbdd_recorrer_rs)

bbdd_conectar() -  Procedure that only open the database connection.

bbdd_recorrer_rs() - Procedure to select data from database and put in a resultset that is added to modelo (modelo.addRow(fila);) that is show in jtable.

how can I see the updated content of the query in the jtable in each of the iterations of the for and not only in the last?

This is the code.

```
// imports ...

public class MonitorSesionesNuevo {

           // Constantes
           public static final Color  CLASE_APPLICATION = Color.BLUE.darker();                        
....   
           public ResultSet rs;         
   
           // Modelo de datos de jtable
           public DefaultTableModel modelo;
           public JTable t_eventos;
           public Object[] fila;
   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MonitorSesionesNuevo();
    }

    public MonitorSesionesNuevo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }


                // Realiza la conexion a la base de datos. 
                bbdd_conectar();

                modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
                modelo.addColumn("Momento");
                modelo.addColumn("CLASE");
                modelo.addColumn("EVENTO");

                t_eventos = new JTable(modelo);
                t_eventos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("ControlSesionesNuevo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(t_eventos));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                

                // Recorremos el resulset con los datos sacados de la bd
            for (int z=1; z<=5; z++)
            {                
                bbdd_recorrer_rs();
                frame.setVisible(true);  
                try {
                    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);  
   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println(e);    
                }
                
                //frame.setVisible(false); 
            }

                frame.setVisible(true);                

            }
        });
    }

    public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            Object vClase = table.getValueAt(row, 0);     // Columna 0, ClASE          
            String SClase = vClase.toString();
         
            switch(SClase) {
                case "CPU":
                  // code block
                  cellComponent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  cellComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  break;
                case "Other":
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  break;
                default:
                  // code block
              }


            return cellComponent;

        }

    }

    public void bbdd_recorrer_rs()
    {
                    // Consultamos la bd
                    try {
                            modelo.setRowCount(0); 
                            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                            int i=1;
                            while (rs.next())
                            {
                                    Object[] fila = new Object[9]; // 9 columnas
                                    // Metemos los 9 campos que leemos en la bd en una fila del jtable. 
                                    fila = new Object[9]; // 9 columnas
                                    for (int k = 0; k<9; k++) {
                                            fila[k] = rs.getObject(k+1);
                                    }

                                    // Añade al jtable en una sola fila todos los campos que nos traemos en el resultset
                                    modelo.addRow(fila);
                                    i++;
                            }
                            rs.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                            // catching the exception
                            System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    // Fin Consulta a la bd

    }

}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Regards

Comment: Get rid of the loop and use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html); for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496126/values-repeating-when-populating-a-jtable/16496193#16496193); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538237/coloring-jtable-cells-based-on-an-array-created-by-tetris-game/15538535#15538535)

Comment: Thank you very much Madprogrammer I was going crazy with this. The problem is solved.